# learning .net core 3.1 - very first attempt at consuming API webservice

Tags: c#, .net, json, api

I'm brand new to .net core 3.1 - not a lot of oop experience period - I have 20 years software development experience using procedural languages on IBMi. Been working through a tutorial to consume an API that I have created on my IBMi... I'm stuck...

Below is my HomeController... What I'm able to do by running this code thus far...

1.) connects to my IBMi endpoint

2.) it does invoke the correct backend API pgm

3.) backend API pgm does indeed take json string from URI and process it like it should, and produces a json string response.

issues..

1.) ultimately i'd like to pass this json request string in the body and not the URI

2.) while everything is working with passing the json string in the URI, when the json string response is sent back, there is an issue processing that response. My guess is that it is expecting a json object back and not a string.
The error is...

> JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to
> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[coreiWS.Models.ProductKey].
> Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.

the generated json string response is... (or could also contain a trial key value - nonetheless, both are valid json in string format)...

> {
> "success": 0,
> "resultMessage": "Error RST00001R - Invalid - Product Code Already Granted 2 Trial Keys.  Please Email Us At xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com To
> Discuss Your Future Business Requirements Utilizing CoreiRST." }

and the code causing it is...

```
var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            productKeys = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                <IEnumerable<ProductKey>>(responseStream);
```

I would be extremely grateful for anyone that could help guide me in the right direction with getting this working.

the complete HomeController Code is...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    // jhv - add this...
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
    public IEnumerable<ProductKey> productKeys { get; set; }
    public HomeController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    // jhv - add this...
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        //var user = Authenticate().Result;

        //if (user == null)
            //return View();

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
            "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/{\"env\":\"xxx\",\"command\":\"getTrialKey\",\"payload\":{\"productCode\":\"MFT  102A08R EPCA 00007\"}}");
        //request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + user.Token);

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        //request.Headers.Add("text/plain", "{\"env\":\"xxx\",\"command\":\"getTrialKey\",\"payload\":{\"productCode\":\"MFT  102A08R EPCA 00007\"}}       \r\n");

        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            productKeys = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                <IEnumerable<ProductKey>>(responseStream);
        }
        else
        {
            productKeys = new List<ProductKey>();
        }


        return View(productKeys);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JSON is returning a singular object, but you are trying to map it to an `IEnumerable<ProductKey>`.

That might get you through the first error message.